# How can I transform my Dictionary to a Matrix?

Tags: dictionary, matrix, asp.net-mvc-5, tuples

I have this dictionary which has the following definition :

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, int>, Document>
```

The dictionary contains information likes this :

[image]

Now I need to get them in a form like this :

[image]

The number between brackets are the id's.
So I need to display the document under the corresponding combination of ID's.

The title of my document should be displayed in the "Documents"-column.
And under the corresponding language, I want an "X".

Comment: In my tuple :
The first number is BusinessUnit (i.e. HPP).
The second number is DocumentType (i.e. TDS).
The third number is Language (i.e. JP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we solved our problem:

```
    using DocumentLanguageDictionary = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, CustomerPortalDomain.Entities.Document>;
    using DocumentList = System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, CustomerPortalDomain.Entities.Document>>;
    using DocumentTypeDictionary = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, CustomerPortalDomain.Entities.Document>>>;
    using BusinessUnitDictionary = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, CustomerPortalDomain.Entities.Document>>>>;

private BusinessUnitDictionary CreateMatrix(UserPermission userPermission)
    {
        BusinessUnitDictionary matrix = new BusinessUnitDictionary();

        var documentList = userPermission.Documents.GroupBy(x => new { Title = x.Title, BusinessUnitId = x.BusinessUnit.Id, DocumentTypeId = x.DocumentType.Id }, (key, group) => new { key = key, translations = group.ToList() }).ToList();

        foreach (var document in documentList)
        {
            int businessUnitId = document.key.BusinessUnitId;
            if (!matrix.ContainsKey(businessUnitId))
            {
                matrix[businessUnitId] = new DocumentTypeDictionary();
            }

            DocumentTypeDictionary documentDictionary = matrix[businessUnitId];

            int documentType = document.key.DocumentTypeId;
            if (!documentDictionary.ContainsKey(documentType))
            {
                documentDictionary[documentType] = new DocumentList();
            }

            DocumentList list = documentDictionary[documentType];

            DocumentLanguageDictionary languageDictionary = new DocumentLanguageDictionary();
            foreach (var translation in document.translations)
            {
                languageDictionary[translation.Language.Id] = translation;
            }
            list.Add(languageDictionary);
        }

        return matrix;
    }
```

And then in the view we can loop and display the data in the correct format.